# Infinitive: purpose or adjectival

Tags: meaning-in-context, infinitives

> These factors can be something about the person or something about the situation, which can combine [***to determine***] the consumer's motivation [***to process***] product-related information at a given point in time.

I think the first infinitive clause **to determine the consumer's motivation** serves as a purpose adjunct.

But I am not sure about the second infinitive clause,
**to process product-related information at a given point in time**.

Does it also serve as a purpose adjunct  ?
Or is it adjectival and add information to the **consumer's motivation**, 
 telling which kind of motivation.

Comment: No, it's not a purpose adjunct, but a complement of the noun "motivation". We know it's a complement, not a modifier,  because it is licensed (specifically permitted/required) by the noun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *These factors can be something about the person or something about the*
>   *situation, which can combine* [*to determine the consumer's motivation*
>   [*to process product-related information at a given point in time*]].

You are right that the *determine* infinitival clause is a purpose adjunct -- note that "in order" can be inserted: *... which can combine in order to determine ...*

But the *process* infinitival is not an adjunct. It's complement of the noun "motivation". We know it's a complement, not a modifier, because it is licensed (specifically permitted/required) by the noun.

Note that modifier infinitivals are a special kind of relative clause, e.g. *We found* [*a big box to keep the CDs in*].

Comment: Thank you so much . If it's a special kind of relative clause,  is your example sentence the equivalent of "We found a box in which we can keep CDs"?

Comment: @Kathy Yes: in many instances, infinitival relatives have a modal meaning.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer again :)