# What does it mean - To start reading?

Tags: grammar

> This is a good place **to start reading.**

Is the bold part working as a relative clause?

Comment: Not sure what it is, but it's definitely not a relative clause. I've got money on BillJ saying "adjunct".

Comment: probably relevant https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/199982/infinitive-purpose-or-adjectival

Comment: It's a good point in a book (or some other piece of text) to start to read it. For some reason you are being advised not to start at the beginning!

Comment: It's a relative infinitive. These are constructions that work like relative clauses, modifying nouns but not using relative pronouns: _a good place to start reading_, but not *_a good place where/which/that to start reading_. They require _wh_-words only with pied-piped prepositions: _a good place on which to set the basket_ but not *_a good place which to set the basket on_. They often have deontic modal senses of "should" or "must" associated. That is to say, they're very complex.

Comment: @gotube and James K maybe see John Lawler's comment above.

Comment: @JohnLawler That looks like a complete answer

Comment: @JohnLawler, would your answer be different for simple gerunds (e.g. place to eat, place to be, place to sleep)? ¶ And it would be good if it were a real answer, not a comment.

Comment: @RayButterworth Gerunds end in _-ing_ and don't take a _to_ infinitive marker. The phrases you quoted are grammatical.